# filereader shim, cannot get it to work in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

Has anyone managed to get the filereader shim from https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/ to work in IE9.

event.target.files is undefined, I cannot get any information about the file selected?

I have

```
$('#fp_file').on('change',function() {
    fileSelected( $(this) );
}); 

// File selected
function fileSelected(ele)
{    

var file = $(ele).prop('files')[0];  

var fileSize = 0;  

if(file)
{
  if(file.size > 1024 * 1024)
  {
      fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
  }
  else
  {
      fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
  }

  $('#fileName').html(file.name);
  $('#fileSize').html(fileSize);
  $('#fileType').html(file.type);
  $('#file_dets').show('slide');

}
else
{
  alert('no file : ' + file);
}
```

}

and the following HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Financial Promotions Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="financial_promotion.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
<script src="js-webshim/minified/extras/modernizr-custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<form id="financial_promotion" action="financial_promotions.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Promotion Documentation&nbsp;</legend>
                    <label for="fp_file">Upload File</label>

                    <input class="ws-filereader" type="file" name="fp_file" id="fp_file" />

            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset id="file_dets">
                <legend>File Information</legend>
                <div>
                    <label for="fileName">Name</label><span id="fileName"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="fileSize">Size</label><span id="fileSize"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="fileType">Type</label><span id="fileType"></span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>                                
   </form>        
   </div>

   </body>
    </html>
```

However, I cannot get access to the file that has been selected, it doesn't seem to matter if I use `$(ele).prop('files')[0];` or `event.target.files` or any other combination, it is always undefined in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

bah humbug!

The example on GITHUB comments out the bit that makes it work!!!

```
//webshims.setOptions('basePath', '/js-webshim/minified/shims/');
```

I saw this in the docs and wrongly assumed it was saying - see this setting - don't use it! - as is the nature of commented out code.

All I needed was to correctly set the basePath and it works.

```
webshims.setOptions({
    'basePath':'/my/folder/path/js-webshim/minified/shims/'
    });

webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext filereader');
```

Hope it helps all the others who's threads I have seen where like me the OP has no hair left!

----> UPDATE 27.05.2014 <----

It is my belief that this polyfil/shim does NOT work. Once you get it running in IE9, you will find that the flash object overrides the input element, so when a file is selected, the underlying input element doesn't get populated with the selected file and so the form can't be submitted as the input is empty.